# Matrices that invert themselves when raised to the $n$-th power

Tags: matrices, inverse, transpose

I'm trying to prove or disprove that if a matrix has the property

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

then

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & c\\b & d\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

This problem isn't really about matrices, it's just method of proving something different about the iteration of rational functions. I don't know that much about matrices, so is there some property about multiplying transposed matrices that would make this any easier?

Comment: See the third property [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties).

Comment: Hint: $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.

Comment: Assuming the matrix name is $M$, It means for example that $M^{n-1} = M^{-1}$. That $M^{-1}$ must exist is a prerequisite for that, but I think it is quite easily proven that it must exist for $M^n = I$ to hold.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got it now.

Comment: Some related posts:
[Matrix chain multiplication with transpose: $(A^n)^T = (A^T)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2054069) and
[Properties of a transpose: $(A^n)^T = (A^T)^n$ and $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1170866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was essentially answered in comments (and judging by [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245067/matrices-that-invert-themselves-when-raised-to-the-nth-power#comment4617695_2245067), the answer was satisfactory for the OP). I'll summarize this in a CW-answer so that the question does not remain unanswered.

We will use this property of a [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties) of a matrix:
$$A^TB^T=(BA)^T\tag{1}.$$
It is not difficult to show this directly from the definition of matrix product. (Probably there are also several posts with a proof on this site. I was able to find relatively quickly 
[Prove $A^tB^t = (BA)^t$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320400/prove-atbt-bat) and
[Assistance with proof of $(AB)^T=B^T A^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440305/assistance-with-proof-of-abt-bt-at).)

Using $(1)$ we get $$(A^n)^T = (A^T)^n$$ by induction.

In particular, if $A^n=I$, then $(A^T)^n = I^T = I$.